# Moments of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have learned that I can compute the moments of a random variable with this formula
$$\mu_n=\mbox{E}(X-\mbox{E}X)^n$$
However, for the moment of order $1$ I can not use this, since I get $\mbox{E}(X-\mbox{E}X)=0$. Then is this formula not correct?

Comment: The moment of order $n$ is defined as $EX^{n}$. Your $\mu_n$ is call the $n-$th central moment. The first central moment is alwasy $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the first order central moment is always zero and is not used.

Instead you can compute the first order *absolute* central moment,

$$E(|X-E(X)|)$$ which is a measure of the spread, like the variance. It is not as efficient, but is more robust.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct and looks more like a definition of *centralized moments*.

BTW if it is replaced by a "correct version" then it is actually a *definition* of moments and not so much a formula  that enables you to *compute* moments.